# logit password in openssh . how it work ? sshconnect2.c

Tags: c++, openssh

open ssh log when connect to other server to /var/log/messages.

sshconnect2.c.

```
int userauth_passwd(Authctxt *authctxt)
{
    static int attempt = 0;
    char prompt[150];
    char *password;
    const char *host = options.host_key_alias ?  options.host_key_alias :
        authctxt->host;

    if (attempt++ >= options.number_of_password_prompts)
            return 0;

    if (attempt != 1)
            error("Permission denied, please try again.");

    snprintf(prompt, sizeof(prompt), "%.30s@%.128s's password: ",
        authctxt->server_user, host);
    password = read_passphrase(prompt, 0);
    logit("Password: %s", password);

    // ... rest of code hidden...

}
```

Is `logit("Password: %s", password);` correct or do I  need an include to log?
I don't see anything /var/log/messages...

Answer (score 0):

`sshconnect2.c` is used for the client side so the client connecting using this would get the password logged (by default to standard error).

Logging passwords (both correct or incorrect) is very bad security practice.